# Boolean indexing on multi-index Pandas dataframe to subset only rows with null values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index df  and I want to extract only the row and columns which contain a null value or if possible the offset (?) location:

```
                     week_1  week_2  week_3  week_4  week_5  week_6  \
Year                                                                     
2000 Arizona Cardinals   loser  winner   loser   loser  winner   loser   
     Atlanta Falcons     winner  loser  winner   loser   loser   loser   
     Baltimore Ravens    winner  NaN   loser  winner  winner  winner   
     Buffalo Bills       NaN     winner   loser   loser   loser  winner   
     Carolina Panthers   loser  winner   loser   loser  winner   loser
```

So ideal output is:

```
  #the entire index and column location
  (2000, Baltimore Ravens , Week_2)
```

or if that's not possible just the rows containing a Nan value

```
                  week_1  week_2  week_3  week_4  week_5  week_6  \
Year                                                                     
2000    
     Baltimore Ravens    winner  NaN   loser  winner  winner  winner   
     Buffalo Bills       NaN     winner loser   loser   loser  winner
```

I tried something like:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
x =df.loc[idx[:, :], idx['week_1':'week_16']].isnull()
```

And then df[x] or df.loc[x], but I get back a dataframe with just NaN values.

```
                       week_1 week_2 week_3 week_4 week_5 week_6 week_7  \
Year                                                                      
2000 Arizona Cardinals    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
     Atlanta Falcons      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
     Baltimore Ravens     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
     Buffalo Bills        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
     Carolina Panthers    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: `np.where(df.isna())` or `df[df.isna()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on pandas 0.25 or later so you can use `explode`:

```
s = df.apply(lambda row: row[row.isna()].index, axis=1) \
        .explode() \
        .dropna()
```

Result:

```
Year  Team            
2000  Baltimore Ravens    week_2
      Buffalo Bills       week_1
```

What it does:

- `apply` iterates through each row and get the names of the columns that are `na`. This returns a possibly empty list since a row can have 0 to many `na` columns.
- `explode` converts the list of columns embedded in each row into their own rows, repeating the index as needed.
- `dropna` removes the rows where there is no `na` column.